# Get an Asset's Filename Without the Extension

Tags: templating, assets

How do I get an asset's filename without the extension? So if my filename is `my_cool_photo.jpg` I want to return `my_cool_photo`. Using `{{ entry.assetsField.one.filename }}` returns the name of the file with the extension included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple method would be to [trim](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/trim.html) the extension from the filename (see [this fiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/ul81i9)):

```
{{ assetsField.filename|trim('.' ~ assetsField.extension, 'right') }}
```